# Creating a conditional redirect PHP form

Tags: php, forms, redirect, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a form that confirms the user has entered one of the allowed email addresses then redirects the user to the page "NewPost.php"; otherwise (if the user has not entered one of the allowed email addresses), they are stuck on this page.  Currently, I can get the entree passed to the next page if I change

```
<form action="Verify.php">
```

to

```
<form action="NewPost.php">
```

but this disregards the conditional.  The form is as follows:

```
<form action="Verify.php" method="post" name="VerifyEmail" id="VerifyEmail">
<p>Please enter your student email address</p>
<p> <input type="text" name="Email" size="40" maxlength="40" required/></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Post" value="Post"/></p>
</form>
```

And the PHP; the *$allowed* variable is the array of schools whose .edu email addresses should meet the conditional to allow the user entering their email address redirect to NewPost.php

```
<?php
$Email = trim($_POST['Email']);
$allowed = array ('columbia.edu', 'nyu.edu', 'fitnyc.edu', 'pratt.edu', 'newschool.edu', 'stjohns.edu', 'cooper.edu', 'manhattan.edu', 'pace.edu', 'bard.edu', 'berkeleycollege.edu', 'qc.cuny.edu');
$split = explode($Email, "@");
    $name = $split['0'];
    $school = $split['1'];
if ($school == $allowed) {
header('Location: /NewPost.php');
}
else{echo "<p>Sorry your school is not supported yet</p>";}
?>
```

To clarify, I want the visit entering their email address to be redirected to NewPost.php only if their email address is within the *$allowed* array, otherwise they're stuck on the current page (Verify.php).
If anyone wants to try it themselves, the address is [here](http://collegeagora.org/Verify.php)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a string to an array. You can't do that. You need to look to see if that string is *in* the *array*. Use either `in_array()` or `isset()`:

```
if (in_array($school, $allowed)) {
```

or

```
if (isset($allowed[$school])) {
```

Comment: Make sure the values in those variables are what you're expecting. A leading or trailing white space characters will throw things off. Also get rid of the quotes around your array keys: $name = $split[0];
    $school = $split[1];

Comment: The TRIM should take care of the white space?   Unfortunately it's still not working properly.

Comment: You have another error. You are calling explode with the parameters backwards. `$split = explode("@",$Email);`